# autocomplete on change event is working only after loosing focus

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete, onchange

I'm using an autocomplete field in my php page. And i need to change the table contents based on the value selected in autocomplete field.

i've tried using on autocompletechange like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#location").on("autocompletechange", function(event,ui){
        $("#table").hide();
            $("#loading").show();
            view_shops();
    });
});
</script>
```

But the filter is applying only after the autocomplete looses its focus. so, the user might think it is taking longer time to load or they might say its an error.
Please suggest me how to make it work on changing the autocomplete field.

Comment: Which autocomplete Javascript do you use? Could you supply a short working example that it is easy to reproduce (and fix) the problem?

Comment: '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">' i'm using these